# Suppress title page for "part" in KOMA scrbook

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, chapters, parts, scrbook

I'm working on typesetting a book that has lovely artwork for chapter headings plus full-page art for each part (so Part 1 gets art that incorporates the text "Part 1", etc.) I successfully suppressed the chapter heading with:

```
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makechapterhead\@gobble % make \@makechapterhead do nothing
  \chapter{#1}
  \endgroup
}
```

(This does work, but Koma complains about the redefinition of @makechapterhead. I'm ok with that for now, but ideally I'd like a solution that doesn't annoy Koma.)

However, I'd like to do the same with \part as well as \chapter, and I can't get this to work.

Here's a MWE where the table of contents and page spreads are just right, BUT I don't want the page with "Part 1" or the blank page opposite it to print:

```
\documentclass[twoside,chapterprefix,headings=big]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mwe}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makechapterhead\@gobble
  \chapter{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\KOMAoptions{headings=openleft}
\part{It begins}
%beautiful artwork goes... around here somewhere?
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-golden}

\KOMAoptions{headings=openright}
\mychapter{a chapter}
 \begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
%beautiful chapter head artwork goes here
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\mychapter{another chapter}
 \begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
%beautiful chapter head artwork goes here
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\KOMAoptions{headings=openleft}
\part{The middle bit}
%beautiful artwork goes... around here somewhere?
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-golden}

\KOMAoptions{headings=openright}
\mychapter{yet another chapter}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

(We're pretending that the "golden" image is the full-page artwork to be used in lieu of LaTeX outputting "Part N: Title".)

I want the page with "Part N: Title" and the blank page opposite it suppressed (not printed). The document should go straight from the table of contents to a two-page spread with the part artwork on the left and the chapter starting on the right.

Creating a \newcommand analogous to \mychapter doesn't appear to do anything, not even put anything interesting in the log:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makeparthead\@gobble
  \part{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Trying to fake a part by *omitting* the `\part{It Begins}` command and instead doping the ToC with

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part \thepart: It Begins}
```

results in the part heading showing up in the table of contents *below* chapter 1, and with no part number, plus I don't see how to increment \thepart so that subsequent parts are numbered correctly. Trying to manually increment it with `\stepcounter{\thepart}` throws an error.

If the Koma guide in English covers this, I honestly missed it.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, that I understand what you want exactly. But
instead of fiddling with internals of the class, I would suggest to define a command, that does exactly what you want and nothing else. AFAIK you want:

- start a new odd page (for chapters) or a new even page (for parts)
- step the counter
- optional add a TOC entry and a mark for page headers
- print an image

I'm using an optional argument for the TOC entry and the mark. And I'm also defining a star variant without increasing the number and without TOC entry and mark similar to `\part*` and `\chapter*`. I'm using the mandatory argument for the image file:

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix,headings=big]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\ArtPart{som}{%
  \cleardoubleevenpage
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% star version: no TOC entry or page header
  }{%
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{% optional argument: Use for TOC entry and page header
      \addparttocentry{\thepart.}{#2}%
      \partmark{#2}%
    }{}%
  }%
  \noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#3}%
  \par\nobreak
  \@afterindentfalse% don't indent first paragraph after the heading
  \@afterheading% don't allow page break here etc.
}

\NewDocumentCommand\ArtChapter{som}{%
  \cleardoubleoddpage
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% star version: no TOC entry or page header
  }{%
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{% optional argument: Use for TOC entry and page header
      \addchaptertocentry{\thechapter}{#2}%
      \chaptermark{#2}%
    }{}%
  }%
  \noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#3}%
  \par\nobreak
  \@afterindentfalse% don't indent first paragraph after the heading
  \@afterheading% don't allow page break here etc.
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\ArtPart[It begins]{example-image-golden}


\ArtChapter[a chapter]{example-image-a}
\blindtext

\ArtChapter[another chapter]{example-image-b}
\blindtext

\ArtPart[The middle bit]{example-image-golden}

\ArtChapter[yet another chapter]{example-image-c}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also, that `\thepart` is not the counter but the output of the counter. The counter would be `part` and therefore to manipulate the counter you have to use `\stepcounter{part}`, `\refstepcounter{part}`, `\addtocounter{part}{…}`, and `\setcounter{part}{…}`, but not `\stepcounter{\thepart}`. Note also, that there isn't a predefined `\@makeparthead` in KOMA-Script.

For more information about `\NewDocumentCommand` see [“LaTeX for authors — current version”](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/usrguide.pdf). For more information about the KOMA-Script commands used, see the KOMA-Script manual.

If you really want to use `\part` and `\chapter` you should IMHO redefine `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` and `\partlineswithprefixformat` instead of internal commands:

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix,headings=big]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand\mypart[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \KOMAoption{open}{left}%
    \renewcommand*{\partlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#2}% this is the second argument of
                                % \mypart not of \partlineswithprefixformat
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\partheademptypage}{}% don't add an empty page after \part
    \part[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup  
}

\newcommand\mychapter[2]{%
  \KOMAoption{open}{right}%
  \DeclareCommandCopy\ChapterLinesWithPrefixFormat\chapterlineswithprefixformat
  \renewcommand*{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#2}% this is the second argument of
                         % \mychapter not of \chapterlineswithprefixformat
  }%
  \chapter[#1]{#2}%
  \DeclareCommandCopy\chapterlineswithprefixformat\ChapterLinesWithPrefixFormat
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\mypart{It begins}{example-image-golden}


\mychapter{a chapter}{example-image-a}
\blindtext

\mychapter{another chapter}{example-image-b}
\blindtext

\mypart{The middle bit}{example-image-golden}

\mychapter{yet another chapter}{example-image-c}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

With this, you still can use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to, e.g., change the vertical distance before and after the heading = before and after the image.

As you can see, I've not needed any internal command for this second suggestion, but only commands that are documented in the KOMA-Script manual to be used for users or advanced users or that are documented in [“LaTeX for authors — current version”](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/usrguide.pdf).

Note: I've not used `\begingroup…\endgroup` in `\mychapter`, because this would also break the possibility to add a `\label` after `\mychapter` and also breaks the `afterindent=false` feature of `\RedeclareSectionCommand`. Instead I've stored the meaning of `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` before `\chapter` and restored it after `\chapter`.

For the first suggestion I've only needed  `\@afterindentfalse` and `\@afterheading` from the LaTeX kernel. These are usual commands for class/package authors but not internal KOMA-Script commands.

Comment: THANK YOU! That's perfect! Thanks also for pointing me to that LaTeX for Authors document, which I hadn't been aware of.